# Pojos in interfaces

Tags: java, json, xml, dependency-injection, jersey

For studies I programmed a `songWebservice`, a REST-service with Jersey, deployed in Tomcat. The database is a local json-file. The `dataService` has an interface `ISongDB` and is used with dependency-injection and an abstract binder. All fine.

Now (next task) the `songWebService` will be improved and the local json will be replaced with an external database.

To avoid copying interfaces, importing useless implementations or putting it all in one project I moved the interfaces into an independent project which I refer in my pom.xml. So now I have two projects with the following:

```
-songWebServiceInterface
  -src.main...songWebService
    - web
      - ISongWebService                             [ Song getSong(id); int postSong(song) ]
      - AbstractSongWebService impl ISongWebService [ protected ISongDB;]
    - database
      - ISongDB                                     [ Song getSong(id); int postSong(song) ]
      - Abstract impl ISongDB                       [ protected abstract void init() ]
    - pojo ???


-songWebServiceFileDB
  -src.main...songWebService
    - web
      - SongWebService extends AbstractSongWebService      
    - database
      - FileSongDB extends AbstractSongDB                
    - pojo ???
```

My problem are the pojos (`Song`).

First in interface-project I used an interface `ISong`, with getters and setters for all attributes. In fileDB-project I put a `Song` implementation of `ISong`. It felt good until object-mapping. I wasn't able to transform a json or xml in an `ISong` and passing it as `Song` through the web or receiving a json or xml and passing it as `ISong` in my file.

I really think that can work but I found no hints how to map an interface. Of course I bind the `Song` to `ISong`, but something else is missing. Please provide me with a pattern and/or an example.

A work-around-solution was to put the `Song` directly without interface in the interface-project. It works, but it is really ugly - now I need to define database-related and mapping/marshalling-related annotations in the interface-project, what really is not what I wanted (perhaps I want to use different database-structures in different implementations).
I thought about using reflection to add the annotations "by code" in the implementation, but I think this is not the way it should go.

I'm really sure there is a common pattern for this, but I got lost.

Where and how shall I implement the pojos with the goals:

- using them in interface to define methods
- customize them with annotations and custom logic in implementations?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot transform JSON to an interface - you need a class to create, i.e. you need the class on both ends.

There is really no point in using interfaces for data objects. Put the data/model classes in the interface artifact instead of using interfaces for them - it's unlikely you'll ever need two different implementations of a model class.

As for not wanting the storage-related annotations in the interface artifact, you're right it feels like bad design. My approach would be that there are two different models involved now:

- Model used for JSON communication
- Data storage model

I would make them two different sets of classes, share the REST API model in the interface artifact and keep the storage model / DTO in the DB artifact.